# Remove charcter from right and left using TCL

Tags: tcl

I am a newbie in TCL and in need of a TCL method / utility / code which can find and remove two characters "("  and ")" in a string from its first occurrence in a string.

I have a string like below:

```
(A-B,C);
```

In the above string I need to remove "(" and ")" and create a list like:

```
A-B,C
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are stripping *all* the parentheses from either end of the string, use `string trim`:

```
set trimmed [string trim $theStr "()"]
```

If you only want to remove *one* pair (and both need to be present for you to want to remove them), that's a job for `regsub`:

```
regsub {^\((.*)\)$} $theStr {\1} trimmed
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the semicolon part of your string? If not:

```
set input "(A-B,C)"
set result [string trim $input "()"]
echo $result
```